# IAM policies for updating cloudwatch ARN on AWS APIGateway settings?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am stuck on trying to figure out what permission require for a role to have the ability to update CloudWatch ARN on AWS APIGateway settings. I added full permission for APIGateway and Cloudwatch and CloudwatchLog to a test role and still can't update the Cloudwatch ARN.

Only adding AdministratorAccess then it worked. I don't want to do that. Did I miss something.

error message

Update Cloudwatch ARN for APIGateway.
{ [AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::*:user/* is not authorized to access this resource]
  message: 'User: arn:aws:iam::**:user/* is not authorized to access this resource',
  code: 'AccessDeniedException',
  time: Thu May 05 2016 11:06:32 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  requestId: '**',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 9.588389308191836

Thanks

Guang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the User has **PassRole** permission on the CloudWatch ARN, API Gateway will consider that the user is authorized to access the resource.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I need to use PassRole for the user then it worked.